# c++ program crash when using regex

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, g++, mingw32

my code after compile crash when reaches to regex part:

I want check is any number exists in received string or no.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int in, count, rate;
    char *w;
    cin >> count;

    for(in = 1; in < 5; in++) {
        rate = 0;
        cin >> w;
        cout << "Case #";
        cout << in;
        cout << ":";

        if (regex_match (std::string(w), regex("([0-9])")))
            ++rate;
        cout << rate;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So where are you allocating memory for that `char *` variable? After you figure that out, don't forget to release it as well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a pointer with no allocated memory. This will crash your program. Just declare it as a string, and try to avoid naked pointers:

```
std::string w;
```

Comment: Now crash for [0-9] in regex. when i change it  program works fine

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this kind of mistake in the feature, please enable warnings, i.e. `-Wall`:

```
main.cpp:6:18: warning: 'w' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     cin >> w;
```

Before using `w`, you need to allocate memory for it. Generally in C-style code, you can either use an array with automatic storage:

```
char w[80]; // some arbitrary number guaranteed to be large enough to hold
            // user input
```

or dynamic memory:

```
char* w = new char[80];
// ...
delete[] w;
```

As stated in another answer, it is more idiomatic to use `std::string` in C++ as it handles the memory for you. This also avoids you creating all those unnecessary temporaries later in your code:

```
if (regex_match (std::string(w), regex("([0-9])")))
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```